# Merge csv file with header

Tags: c#, csv, merge, header

I have a comma delimited csv file without header and I have a header in a separate file. What would be the most efficient way of merging the two together?

Comment: you can use readalltext method of File class, set it into a two variable and then concat them and save into file

Answer (score 0):

```
string pathToHeader = @"C:\Path\To\Header.csv";
string pathToNoHeader = @"C:\Path\To\NoHeader.csv";

string headerText = File.ReadAllText(pathToHeader);
string noHeaderText = File.ReadAllText(pathToNoHeader);

File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Path\To\Output.csv", string.Concat(headerText, noHeaderText));
```

Comment: I was looking more for something where I could insert a line into a file at the first line